# eGPUs for 3D content creation

Tags: gpu, thunderbolt, 3d-graphics

**Note: I realize the "discussion-ness" of this topic, so I'll try my best to phrase it as a question**

I'm interested to know the effectiveness of an eGPU for 3D content creation (animation, game dev, arch-vis).

Regarding eGPUs, I'm aware of the following:

1. "full potential" of a GPU can be limited due to the bandwidth of TB3
2. Can be cheaper than buying a full tower
3. Certain systems do not support the use of eGPUs

Here are my questions regarding this topic:

1. Since 3D rendering is obviously a slower process than trying to spit out frames in a game, does the whole bandwidth issue not matter anymore? What does the limited bandwidth mean when using an eGPU?
2. What causes a system to be unable to use an eGPU?
3. Are there issues regarding using an eGPU through an internal monitor vs using an external monitor?

The system I'm personally targetting for an eGPU would be my (measly) Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 370 (i5, 8GB RAM).

Thank you in advance for your help on this topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the limited bandwidth mean when using an eGPU?

When speaking of eGPUs specifically, it generally refers to the connection medium (Thunderbolt 3, USB, PCIe, etc.) and that specific connection's maximum theoretical bandwidth. Inside a PC with an internal GPU, this is accomplished by directly connecting the GPU to the motherboard's PCIe lanes.

Thunderbolt 3 is limited to a maximum throughput of 5 GB/sec. PCIe Gen 3 x16 (what most GPUs nowadays use) is around 16 GB/sec, a little over 3x that of Thunderbolt 3. However, it should be noted that in real-world use, it's unlikely that a GPU will ever need that much bandwidth and 5 GB/sec (Thunderbolt 3) should be adequate for most applications, including games.

> What causes a system to be unable to use an eGPU?

It depends on the eGPU/enclosure you use to hold the GPU. There are PCIe enclosures that provide a PCIe feed directly to the eGPU which require a corresponding PCIe connection on the PC. To use a Thunderbolt 3 eGPU enclosure, you'd need a Thunderbolt 3 port. If your system doesn't support the connection medium, it won't support use of the eGPU/enclosure.

As the use of external GPUs is still an emergent technology, it should also be noted that there are no real standards for how eGPUs should operate or how enclosures should communicate. So, there is a level of uncertainty when you buy one if it will work with your PC, even if it does support the connection method. The best thing to do would be to look up other users' experiences with a specific eGPU/enclosure to get a better idea of what will work with your system.

> Are there issues regarding using an eGPU through an internal monitor vs using an external monitor?

It depends on the system. Generally, to leverage a GPU's power in a real-time application, your monitor needs to be connected directly to the GPU. That means you may not be able to use your laptop's built-in screen with the eGPU. I don't know enough about this to speak on it, but it could be possible to "route" that video back through the integrated graphics using a method similar to what YouTuber Linus from Linus Tech Tips did in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rxFxdvO3fQ).

As for your laptop, the Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 370, you should have a Thunderbolt 3 USB-C port on that machine. I've seen several posts online about successful use of an eGPU with that model. It should be able to use any external GPU enclosure that supported Thunderbolt 3 (which is a decent number of them). Keep in mind that you may not get full performance from the eGPU because it's using Thunderbolt 3, and you may need to connect an external monitor to the eGPU in order to use it.

All that being said, I'd recommend just buying/building a desktop PC with an integrated GPU unless portability is an absolute must for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response and for your help! I'm wondering though, does the bandwidth limitation of Thunderbolt 3 affect performance in non-game scenarios? If so, by how much? I guess I'm not incredibly well versed in GPU technology, and I do not know how a GPU would handle these scenarios (are they treated the same or are they different)

Comment: They are very similar. Generally though, 3D modeling and CAD programs should require less bandwidth than games. One of the main reasons for this is 3D modeling/CAD software usually doesn't use texturing as much as video games would. That's important because textures account for a significant portion of the data transfers between the PC and the GPU.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for you help!